# .bash_profile not sourced when running su

Tags: rhel, environment-variables, su

I have a user, say `user1`, which has modifications to its `.bash_profile`, one of them changing the `PATH`, e.g.: `export PATH=/some/place:$PATH`. This change works fine if I log on as `user1` or do a `su - user1`.

But if I try to run a command via `su` as `root`, e.g.:

```
su -c test.sh oracle
```

(test contains `echo $PATH`)

It doesn't seem to have the modified `PATH` (or root's `PATH`, for that matter). I've also tried copying `.bash_profile` to `.profile`, to no avail.

Why is this happening?

Comment: use --login switch to `su`

Comment: FYI -- nice writeup on bash configuration files http://hacktux.com/bash/bashrc/bash_profile

Comment: @NikhilMulley you link is not working. Can post this to another blog ?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Using `su` without `-l` or `-` starts `bash` as an interactive, but non-login shell, which doesn't read from either of the files you specified. Use the `-l` or `-` option or put the relevant config into `/root/.bashrc`.

Quick summary of config files:

- Login shell (`-l`/`--login`) reads `/etc/profile` first, and then the first it finds of: `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`.
- Interactive but non-login shell (`-i`) reads `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc`, in that order (unless the `--rcfile` option is used and tells it to look elsewhere).
- Non-interactive shells, e.g. started from within another program without using the `-l` or `-i` flags, reads the file specified in the `BASH_ENV` environment variable.
- When run as `sh` as a login shell, it will read `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile`, in that order.
- When run as `sh` as an interactive non-login, it reads the file specified in `ENV`.

Comment: I landed here because I created a new user, and I didn't make sure I set the shell to bash... you can check `/etc/passwd` for that

Answer (score 5):

Bash behaves differently depending on if it believes that it is a login shell, i.e. the first shell run when you log onto a system.  It only reads `.bash_profile` if it is a login shell.  If you put the `PATH`-changing code into `.bashrc` instead, it will be run for all interactive bash shells, not just login shells.

Answer (score 0):

If using the Gnome environment in Scientific Linux 6 (or presumably RHEL 6), start a terminal.  Go to `Edit` -> `Profile Preferences` -> `"Title and Command"` tab.  Make sure that the checkbox "Run command as a login shell" is checked.  I found that the Gnome terminal application is ignoring my `.bash_profile` unless I do this.