# How to define a Bash function that can be used by different scripts

Tags: bash, shell-script, function

I have defined a `bash` function in my `~/.bashrc` file. This allows me to use it in shell terminals. However, it does not seem to exist when I call it from within a script.

How can I define a `bash` function to be used by scripts as well?

Comment: But my .bash_profile basically reads the .basrc file, so I would expect the result to be the same regardless I use login or non-login shell.

Comment: Are you using `/bin/sh` in the shebang line?

Comment: [Quick summary of which files are automatically sourced when](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29811/11750)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bashrc` are not read by scripts, and functions are not exported by default. To do so, you can use `export -f` like so:

```
$ cat > script << 'EOF'
#!/bin/bash
foo
EOF
$ chmod a+x script
$ ./script
./script: line 2: foo: command not found
$ foo() { echo "works" ; } 
$ export -f foo
$ ./script
works
```

`export -f foo` could also be called in `~/.bash_profile` to make this function available to scripts after login. Be warned that `export -f` is not portable.

A better solution would be to source the file containing the function using `. file`. This is much more portable, and doesn't rely on your environment being set up in a particular way.

Comment: why not just declare a function like `function myFunction { ... }` in `~/.bash_profile` and you're good to go?

Comment: If I understood properly your answer (regarding sourcing a file with the function), this would mean that I have to source the file explicitly in every script, which is pretty much annoying. This is not much less complicated than just copy-pasting the function itself in every script. I would save some lines, sure, but that's all.

However, the `export` solution seems to work properly. Thanks.

Comment: @foampile, this is precisely what I did and does not work when calling the function from a script.

Comment: @Onturenio : the second method @chris-down proposed is indeed better:  1) When someone read the script, they are aware that it needs some `foo` function from some `file` 2) You can better control the content of that `file` than make sure that the invoking shell didn't change `foo` before invoking your script. You could add safety checks on `file` to make sure it's untampered, for example. (not easy, but possible). (well, you could also do those checks on the defined foo function... but you get my drift ^^ I think the method 2 is cleaner.) 3) `file` will only contain what's needed, not more.

Answer (score 9):

`.bashrc` is only read by interactive shells. (Actually, that's an oversimplification: bash is quirky in this respect. Bash doesn't read `.bashrc` if it's a login shell, interactive or not. And there's an exception even to the exception: if bash's parent process is `rshd` or `sshd`, then bash does read `.bashrc`, whether it's interactive or not.)

Put your function definitions in a file in a known place, and use the `.` (also spelled `source`) builtin to include that file in a script.

```
$ cat ~/lib/bash/my_functions.bash
foo () {
…
$ cat ~/bin/myscript
#!/bin/bash
. ~/lib/bash/my_functions.bash
foo bar
```

If you want, you can follow ksh's autoload feature. Put each function definition in a file with the same name as the function. List the directories containing the function definitions in the `FPATH` variable (a colon-separated list of directories). Here's a crude approximation of ksh's `autoload` which actually loads the function immediately instead of on-demand:

```
autoload () {
  set -- "$(set +f; IFS=:;
            for d in $FPATH; do
              if [ -r "$d/$1" ]; then echo -E "$d/$1"; break; fi;
            done)"
  [[ -n $1 ]] && . "$1"
}
```

Comment: +1 for autoload, although I recommend using the ones that come with bash. The latest one supports lazy load.

Answer (score 1):

Do you *need* a function? If not, consider pulling out the logic into a separate, stand-alone Bash script in your `$PATH`. For example, I had this in my `~/.bashrc`:

```
# echo public IP address
alias wanip='dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com'
```

`~/bin` is in my `$PATH`, so I created `~/bin/wanip` with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

# echo public IP address
dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
```

And ran `chmod 0755 ~/bin/wanip` to make it executable. Now I can execute `wanip` from other scripts.

I like having `wanip` in a stand-alone Bash script. It reminds me that I want this logic generally available (besides just in my current interactive Bash session). The script nicely encapsulates the logic and documentation for same.