# Linux (RedHat) `sudo su -l <<user_acct>>` does not source profile

Tags: linux, rhel, sudo, profile

As stated, having trouble with loading the default profile of `<<user_acct>>` when doing `sudo su -l <<user_acct>>`.

Inside `.profile`,

```
if [ -r "${HOME}/.profile.custom" ]; then
    . "${HOME}/.profile.custom"
fi
```

From what I've read (for example, answers similar to this [one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29791/bash-profile-not-sourced-when-running-su)), `-l` should have triggered a login shell and therefore sourced `.profile`, but it doesn't seem to be working because the environment variables set in `.profile.custom` is not there (vs. if I just ran `. .profile`, they show up.

**Revised question**: Any thoughts why or **how to get around this issue**?

Comment: Are you using Bash?  What directory is `.profile` in?  Why `~/.profile.custom` instead of just putting the "custom commands" in `~/.profile` (that's what it's there for)?

Comment: @depquid Yes on Bash... actually I found out that I should be using `.bash_profile` instead to set the additional env variables.  `.profile` is under the home directory of the `<<user_acct>>`.  As for `.profile.custom`... no particular reason I guess, just that these are custom things so we put it in a custom file (just our team's preference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it's a login shell, bash first looks for `~/.bash_profile`. If it doesn't find it, it looks for `~/.bash_login`. If it doesn't find it, it looks for `~/.profile`. In any case, even if the login shell is interactive, bash doesn't read `~/.bashrc`.

I recommend to stick to the following content in `~/.bash_profile`, and to not have a `~/.bash_login`:

```
if [ -e ~/.profile ]; then . ~/.profile; fi
case $- in *i*) if [ -e ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi;; esac
```

That way your `.profile` is loaded whether your login shell is bash or some other sh variant, and your `.bashrc` is loaded by bash whether the shell is a login shell or not.

Comment: I can definitely see a benefit to setting up an OS-agnostic profile.  I'm going to mark your answer as accepted since there are learning points that I think could benefit others. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Don't do `sudo su`, that's not needed. `sudo -i -u loginname` is what you want.

Comment: This looks really promising, but unfortunately I am not allowed to run this command on my team. Or rather, our admin didn't want to open up the ability to run `bash` under the `<<user_acct>>`... Not really seeing why we shouldn't open up the permission if we already have `sudo su` but out of my control *shrug*

Comment: Yeah, you are running Bash as "`<<user_acct>>`"; that's why it's called `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 0):

The author of the question provided the following solution:

> I found a solution for my problem after all... Turns out it was rather trivial - just set the environment variables in `.bash_profile` instead and they are set.
>
> According to the `bash` man page, as discussed [here](http://stefaanlippens.net/bashrc_and_others),
>
> > When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists. **After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.** The --noprofile option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.
>
> .. the key lies in the ***first*** one that exists.
>
> *Lesson learned: read the "fine" print*